# Overloading a function with a data type in Haskell

Tags: haskell, overloading

If I've declared a data type thus:

`data ExampleType = TypeA (Int, Int) | TypeB (Int, Int, Int)`

How can I declare a function that takes either TypeA or TypeB and performs different operations on that basis? My current attempt is:

```
exampleFunction :: ExampleType -> Int
exampleFunction (TypeA(firstInt, secondInt)) = --Fn body
exampleFunction (TypeB(firstInt, secondInt, thirdInt)) = --Fn body
```

But I'm getting a `Duplicate type signatures` error, so I'm clearly missing something.

Comment: [Not reproducible](http://ideone.com/jdnPpO)

Comment: This code does not cause a _duplicate type signatures_ error.

Comment: Aside: this has nothing to do with overloading. `exampleFunction` is a single function. `TypeA (2,3)` and `TypeB (4,5,6)` are different values of the same type, exactly like 2 and 3.

Comment: And now it's not producing that error. *sigh* Thanks for the help.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Works for me:

```
data ExampleType = TypeA (Int, Int) | TypeB (Int, Int, Int)

exampleFunction :: ExampleType -> Int
exampleFunction (TypeA (a,b)) = a + b
exampleFunction (TypeB (a,b,c)) = a + c + c

main = print $ exampleFunction (TypeA (2,3))
```

http://ideone.com/jsIBVF

Note that you typically wouldn't use tuples as components of your type, as this makes it quite hard to get to the data. If you have not a very good reason, simply use 
`data ExampleType = TypeA Int Int | TypeB Int Int Int`

Comment: You're... quite right. It does compile. But it wasn't compiling half an hour ago... Your advice on data types is good though, thanks you.

Answer (score 2):

Your code should not cause such an error. However there some things wrong with your question. First the use of a tuple is unsusual for a Product type (`TypeA (Int, Int)`). Instead you would just declare `TypeA` as a data constructor that takes two arguments of type `Int` instead of one of type `(Int, Int)`. Furthermore `TypeA` and `TypeB` are not two different types but two different data constructors of the same sum type `ExampleType`. To reflect that I renamed them to `DataA` and `DataB` in the below code.

```
data ExampleType = DataA Int Int | DataB Int Int Int
exampleFunction :: ExampleType -> Int
exampleFunction (DataA x y) = x + y
exampleFunction (DataB x y z) = x + y + z
```

Comment: Right, though technically nothing is _wrong_ with putting tuples in `data`. It's just unnecessary. It may also be slower, especially slower than the strict version `DataA !Int !Int | DataB !Int !Int !Int`.